# Select option create dynamically after dom on multi select form

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, select, dynamic

Good day, I have a problem with a multi select form, only the first one has options, the second one is filled with ajax according to the selection of the first one and the third one is filled according to the selection of the second and so on.

When I click on a button I send parameters to that form so that the appropriate options are selected, these options are created after loading the DOM and I can not select them with a $(element).prop('selected', true);

If I check the second select it is filled with the options according to the selection of the first one but I can not select the option of the second select and so on, how could I solve this?

thanks for your help.

HTML/Edit button jquery:

```js
$('#example tbody').on("click", "#edit", function(e) {
  button = 'edit';
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#addProduct').modal('show');

  var c = $(this).data('con');
  var typ = $(this).data('typ');
  var va = $(this).data('va');
  var s = $(this).data('s');
  var b = $(this).data('b');

  $('#conservation option:contains("' + c + '")').prop('selected', true);
  $("#conservation").change();

  $('#type option:contains("' + typ + '")').prop('selected', true);
  $("#type").change();

  $('#variant option:contains("' + va + '")').prop('selected', true);
  $("#variant").change();

  $('#size option:contains("' + s + '")').prop('selected', true);
  $("#size").change();

  $('#box option:contains("' + b + '")').prop('selected', true);
  $("#box").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Product type <small style="color: #FF0000;">*</small></label>
    <!-- <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Conservation <small style="color: #FF0000;">*</small></label> -->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control poptions" name="conservation" id="conservation">
        <?php
                        $query="SELECT * FROM `conservation`;";
                        echo '<option value="" selected>Choose...</option>';
                        if ($exec = $conn->query($query)) {
                          while ($res = $exec->fetch_row()) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$res['0'].'">'.$res['1'].'</option>';
                          }
                         $exec->free();
                        }
                      ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Product Presentation <small style="color: #FF0000;">*</small></label>
    <!-- <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Type <small style="color: #FF0000;">*</small></label> -->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control poptions" name="type" id="type">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ajax to load next select

```js
$(document).on('change', '#conservation', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id=' + id;


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetchProType.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $("#type").html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PHP(fetchProType.php) returning to ajax

```php
if($_POST['id']){
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $sql="SELECT B.* FROM product A INNER JOIN producttype B ON B.idProductType = A.idProductType WHERE A.idConservation = '".$id."' AND A.idSA_Status = '1' GROUP BY name;";

    $options = '<option value="" selected>Choose...</option>';
    if ($exec = $conn->query($sql)) {
        $num_rows = $exec->num_rows;

        while($res= $exec->fetch_row()){
            $options .= '<option value="'.$res['0'].'">'.$res['1'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo $options;
}
```

Comment: So the only problem here is you can't `prop('selected' , true)` the second select option .. it doesn't work .. right?? .. And when `console.log(typ)` it gives you a correct value??

Comment: yes, the value of typ is correct, i think is related to elements created after the DOM load so, for the browser this element doesn't exist and jquery cannot select them..

Comment: I don't think so .. you may just need to use `.trim()`  ... `var typ = $(this).data('typ').trim();` to avoid any white spaces

Comment: For check try to select a specific option value .. `$('#type option[value="something"]').prop.....` and see what you'll get

Comment: typ is just one word i just tried directly with the value (is numeric, and is just 1) and doesn't work, there is a way to look all option loaded in type select?

Comment: You can loop through `options` .. `$('#type option').each(function(){ console.log($(this).text();)});`

Comment: i set a timeout and the option is selected well, looks like run most faster the selection function than the populate function, any suggestion on this?

Comment: Sorry .. Yes I got the point now.. After a lot of think you're right .. the ajax takes time to take effect so you need to use `timeout` and I don't think its a good idea OR you can control the selected option from php not in js .. you'll need to use `data` attribute   to make it work with the same js code you already coded instead of write another code

Comment: When I got a time I will make an answer for you because its a little bit long answer

Comment: Also try to take a look at http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ And https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ And http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/   may help

Comment: thanks Mohamed, i will take a look

Comment: `#example tbody` ...I don't see any table.  `var c = $(this).data('con');
      var typ = $(this).data('typ');
      var va = $(this).data('va');
      var s = $(this).data('s');
      var b = $(this).data('b');` ...I don't see any data-* attributes. If they are to be dynamically created, where's an example when they exist?

Comment: for people like you, power ranger said their colors...